# DAG Exchange 2010 error

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012

I got two exchange 2010 servers with both the following roles (CAS, HUB, MB). Server A (192.168.50.16) is in a different site then server B (192.168.51.16). I have created a DAG with the ip adresses 192.168.50.17 and 192.168.51.17 with a witness share on a random server. Server A has 1 active DB's with a copy on Server B and Server B has 2 active DB's with a copy on server A. Every day when I log on to Server A I can see that the active DB is not mounted anymore on this server but all DB's are mounted on Server B and I can see in the event viewer that there is a cluster failover problem. I get on my cluster the following events 1069, 1564 and 1562. Checked my witness share permissions, set my crossite treshold higher, checked my ip adresses and in the cluster manager everything is up. Any idea what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I though I already added the group "exchange trusted subsystem" to the administrator's group of the witness server but I didn't. After I did this everything works fine.